# Smoothing the current drawn by a PWM load

Tags: current, pwm

*Just to clarify one thing first: I'm not trying to smooth the output voltage from a PWM signal - I would just use an appropriate capacitor for that purpose.*

So, I have made some heated insoles for my wife (she struggles with chilblains, and nothing on the market kept her toes sufficiently warm). The insoles generate heat using Nichrome wire and are powered by a USB battery pack. Each insole draws about 1.2A at 5V, which the battery pack is quite happy with and lasts a few hours.

The insoles work great but sometimes needed to be turned down a little bit, so I used a [cheap PWM LED dimmer](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004693286648.html) to control the heat output. This works great except when reducing the heat output, the battery pack shuts off after a while.

My USB battery pack shows a 2.1 amp mode and a 1 amp mode on its display. When on full power, it automatically switches to 2.1 amp mode. When on a lower power, it automatically switches to 1 amp mode. My current theory is that the battery pack has a resettable fuse inside, which breaks the circuit because I am actually still drawing 1.2 amps during the PWM cycle.

Here's a diagram of my circuit so far:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

My question is: **How can I "smooth" the current that I am drawing from the battery pack so I don't draw more than 1 amp on the lower PWM settings?**

Comment: Can you show the schematic of the dimmer you used please? I mean, without it it's just guesswork as to whether adding an output inductor will cause the dimmer to fail. What PWM frequency does it use? Please provide technical details of the battery.

Comment: That's a good question @Andyaka. As with these cheap imports, it doesn't come with much documentation. I did pull one apart and it has a 13.52127Mhz crystal oscillator on it and some mysterious unlabelled ICs. I suspect that it uses a microcontroller for switching a MOSFET to generate the PWM, although the PWM frequency is unclear, which isn't very helpful I know!

Comment: I also don't have much on the battery itself, but I would prefer it if the solution didn't rely on specific details of the power source (i.e. I should be able to safely swap out the battery pack or use a USB wall adapter)

Comment: You could try a capacitor across the input to the PWM module. USB spec apparently says 10uF is maximum allowable but you could try higher (eg. 100uF electrolytic capacitor).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think the dimmer might already have input capacitance and this could *cause* the battery to shutdown, so more ripple isolation might be required as per user4574's answer

Comment: @tobalt It's possible, not much room in that product for caps though. I suggest trying simple things first.

Comment: Why use a PWM instead of a regular potentiometer? This isn't AC, this is DC power.

Comment: Can you put the insoles in series?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not sure how a capacitor would help. When the load is "active", it will be drawing power from the battery, not the capacitor. When the load is "inactive", the capacitor won't draw any current from the battery. I believe all this would do is increase the startup current while the capacitor is charging.

Comment: @svin83 The pot would be simple but wouldn't be the most efficient way to turn the heat down. When set at 1 ohm resistance, my circuit would draw roughly 1 amp. I would still have 4V across the heater wire (ignoring the indicator LED for now), giving me about 4 watts of heater power in the insoles. However, the pot would be turning about 1 watt of power into heat as well (leaving a very warm pocket and some wasted energy :D)

Comment: @greybeard This would draw 2.4 amps, which is higher than my battery pack can handle on a single output

Comment: Putting the insoles *in parallel* would draw 2.4 A. Putting them in series shouldn't draw *more* than a single one, but less, rather. Given `Nichrome`, expect close to 0.6 A - the question is: will one quarter of *full power* do?

Comment: @greybeard Oops, sorry. I see the point now and thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, quarter power wouldn't do the job. They take a little while to heat up so it's desirable to still be able to access 100% power. About 80% power is just right when sitting at a desk with a cold floor underneath. Quarter power might be alright for taking a walk in cool (but not cold) weather where walking generates some heat as well.

Comment: @JackHarrison The idea is that the capacitor would smooth the current by requiring charge during the PWM off times and supplying part of the current during the PWM on times. It may not work, just something to try.

Answer (score 4):

> The battery pack shuts off after a while.

It may be because of an "auto shutdown feature."  Most power bank system chips come with a no load detection system which measures the output current.  If it is below a certain threshold (~ 50-100 mA) then system assumes no load and shuts down the supply and goes to sleep mode.  They usually wait a certain amount of time before that (about 15-30 seconds.)

You could check if your power-bank shuts off automatically when the consumed current drops. You could use a simple LED and resistor at the power supply output and monitor the change.

Comment: I've found this when running LED bike lights off USB battery packs.  The lower the LED brightness (by PWM) the sooner the battery pack shuts off, but there's a significant random factor on at least one pack I have. I've started to wonder whether the battery pack is polling the current at low frequency and shutting down if it detects a (near-)zero current a few times in a row, rather than high frequency and averaging (the low frequency could equally be a beat between the current measurement frequency and the PWM frequency).

Comment: I suspect that this is the case. Had a problem when most powerbanks but the cheapest ones refused to power ESP32 (which was the only load), because it did not draw enough power.

Comment: This is a solid theory. I'm curious about the simple LED and resistor setup. I can see when my insoles switch off already, so I'm wondering how I can use the extra LED and resistor to test this theory?

Comment: @ Jack Harrison, first disconnect your driver ckt and place a 220Ohms (or < 1K resistor) and led to output of your power-bank also connect an ammeter in series turn on power bank ( if it won't turn on automatically ) and measure the current. case1: led will glow till some time as mentioned above for some time and power bank will auto shut down, if this happens then the reason is same as i mentioned. and you would have to maintain the minimum current requirement of chip to keep power bank on.

Answer (score 3):

“High frequency” PWM is the problem. Due to thermal mass, the heater can be PWM-Ed at say 10Hz. This will present full load current to the pack repeatedly and prevent it from going to sleep. No other filtering is needed: you want the full-current low frequency periods so that the sleep circuit detects them and doesn’t power down the output nor change modes down to 1A.

I’ve faced the same problem, just in a different USB-powered heating application. Running the PWM at a couple to couple dozen Hz made it work with all power packs I had handy.

If you have a USB-C power pack then you can switch the heater to a USB-C connector, and a PD power sink chip/module in the heater to identify yourself as a 3A 5V load. The battery pack won’t shut down then as long as the power contract is active.

Comment: It sounds like you have some experience in this field. I was hoping not to have to create my own PWM circuit (I'll never be able to make it as small as the AliExpress imports and it wouldn't be remote controlled). I don't have a battery pack with a 3A 5V setting, but perhaps this would work nicely with a different battery pack.

Comment: Are you saying that I could run an unfiltered PWM load if I got a simple USB PD decoy (such as [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001668143510.html) and a suitable battery pack?

Answer (score 2):

If the PWM frequency is high enough, just put a pi-filter between the PWM load and the battery pack.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkmSuz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is optional to prevent resonance.  It can be omitted if there is enough resistance elsewhere in the circuit.

Pick L annd C such that the cutoff frequency is several times lower than PWM frequency.  Ignoring resistance, the cutoff frequency is calculated as...

$$f = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

For example, for 100k PWM you might pick. C = 100uF and L = 1uH, which gives a cutoff frequency of 15.9KHz and would give you about 39:1 attenuation.

The resistor R1 should be chosen such that ...

$$ R1 + Capacitor\_ESR + L1\_ESR \ge \sqrt{\frac{4 * L}{C}}$$

In the case of 1uH / 100uF you need at least 0.2 ohms total between the capacitor ESR, inductor ESR, and the resistor R1.

You will want to avoid having too much ESR in the capacitors or it will hurt the performance of the filter.

Comment: In principle this. But instead of a series R, which wastes loads of power, you place a snubber in parallel with C2 to damp possible resonances (usually Al electrolytic capacitor)

Comment: @tobalt I agree with your statement about using a parallel snubber.  But practically speaking, for 5V/2A and using small electrolytic capacitors and a small inductor, the ESR by itself might fulfill the damping requirements either with none, or a very small resistor.  Whether one wants to include the extra snubber depends on how much they want to optimize the design.

Comment: This isn't the correct solution. More likely the power bank is shutting down due to very low load detected. It'll shut down even after adding this 'filter'

Comment: Yes you are right, with something like 0.1 ohm, one seems to be set, but in general don't recommend an extra series resistor. Especially not when using batteries

Comment: @Kripacharya How much "more" likely ? If you dim only a "little" (as stated by OP), the current is likely much higher than 100 mA (perhaps on the order of 0.5-1 Amp) and the input current ripple of the dimmer could well upset the battery too. So it's a valid solution to post here. It is very vague to claim this solution be wrong, when the OP hasn't provided numerical values.

Comment: @tobalt the problem is not in your solution per se, it's in your solution coupled with the OP's statement that he's using a cheap chinese dimmer. Also the fact that when he reduces it a "little", the power bank switches from 2.1A to below 1A. That's NOT a "little". And this despite the fact that it's a 4ohm load...  which should in any case draw only max 1.25A. Something else is going on here...  too many contradictions and unknowns. Hence my comment.

Comment: @Kripacharya I think it's pretty simple, and points to this solution working just fine, as long as the duty cycle stays above 10% or so. The problem is with the unfiltered PWM being seen as periods of near-zero current draw, not with the *average* current being too low.

Comment: For this to work, do I need to know the PWM frequency of the dimmer? Would I need to add some shielding to prevent the inductor from interfering with mobile phones or credit cards in her pocket?

Comment: I would also need to be careful to add as little resistance as possible to the circuit (I understand some will be inevitable if I add anything extra). Assuming an ideal circuit and ignoring the indicator LED for now, it outputs 6.25 watts of heat into the insoles at full power. If I add 0.2ohms in series, then it reduces the total power drawn to 5.95 watts with 0.28 watts lost in the additional resistor, and only 5.67 watts left for the heater (nearly 10% loss of heat output). Perhaps this would be acceptable for this project

Comment: @JackHarrison Using a shielded type of inductor should prevent radiating.  But also note that if you had long wires they were probably already radiating.  If you care about EMI, then place the filter as close to the dimmer input as possible, and possibly even add a filter on the output.

Comment: @JackHarrison If you are concerned about inductor stray field, then get a toroidal inductor.